# CSS of my form module get's weird while and after I insert test (HTML, FORM, CSS)

Tags: html, css, forms, input, placeholder

I have a form module in html and the form looks good when it loads. However, if I click on the box to insert text, the box changes its css (different shape, different color et cetera). Also, When i stop typing and click elsewhere, the box gets back normal but the text I typed is not following the placeholder css.

Also, when I click "subscribe" after I typed the text(second screenshot). It first goes to that weird third screenshot and then I have to click again to actually submit.

MY CSS

```
form {
          text-align: center;
        }
      label {
        font-family:Georgia;
        font-size:1em;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        padding: 0;
      }

      button {
          background-color: #B02E25;
          border: 1px solid;
          border-color: rgba(77,77,77,0.25);
          border-radius: 10px;
          height: 4px;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px 30px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: inline-block;
          font-family:Georgia;
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;
          font-weight: lighter;
        }
      input {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border:0;
        width:300px

      }

      input:focus {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family:Georgia;
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
      }

      ::placeholder {
        color: #aaa;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family:Georgia;
      }

      input:focus::placeholder {
        color: transparent;
      }
```

MY HTML

```
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="" style="position: relative; margin-top: 15em;">
            <div class="col-12" style="  display: flex;  justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                
            </div>
        
            <div class="" style="display: flex;justify-content:center; align-items: center;">
                <form method="post" novalidate>
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Xz4wZIixFDVotjFZqBZ6nIeT0jwX3QW7G9vOpjwPubdC6QI21KlAIisj5eYz48cb">
                    <tr><th></th><td><input type="email" name="email" class="" placeholder="Email you want to spam" maxlength="100" required id="id_email"></td></tr>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">subscribe</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        
        </div>

    </body>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The text you typed should not follow placeholder rule cause it's not placeholder anymore

Comment: What rules does it follows? What html tag should I modify the css of?

Comment: Simply css for `input`

Comment: Mh, I must be doing something wrong. I added some pictures of what the button looks like. Something is off. Also, when I click "subscribe" after I typed the text(second screenshot). It first goes to that weird third screenshot and then I have to click again to actually submit.

Answer (score 0):

fixed doing this

```
form {
        text-align: center;
}

label {
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-size:1em;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
    background-color: #B02E25;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgba(77,77,77,0.25);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:Georgia;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

input {
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border:0;
  width:300px;
  font-size:16px;

}

input:focus {
 /*padding: 10px; */
  text-align: center;
  font-family:Georgia;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);

}


::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:Georgia;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```